# Adding remaining items to another vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have an `std::vector<unsigned int> v` with some índices (for performance purposes I can't use `std::set`.

I want to create the negated version of `v`, i.e., the vector with all the remaining indices. If, in a range `[0,10]`, `v=[0,2,4,6,8]`, I want the negated version, `nv=[1,3,5,7,9]`.

Note: `v` is sorted!

What is the most effective way of doing so?

Comment: Can `v` be modified, say, sorted?

Comment: And, is there another vector representing the range `[0, 10]`? If no, how was it represented?

Comment: @timrau forgot to mention it is already sorted due to previous duplicate removing

Comment: @timrau yes same range. This is actually for OpenGL `DrawElements`

Comment: Could you provide some sample *input* and expected *output*?

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp Well I just did, with v and vn should be the output

Comment: @manatttta so you are *always* going from even to odd, or odd to even? I doubt this is the case, but if it is all you need to do is subtract/add `1` to each element, and you have your inverse.

Comment: `std::set_difference(boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(0), boost::counting_iterator<unsigned int>(11), v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(nv));`

Answer (score 1):

It is linear time.

```
std::vector<unsigned int> getnv(unsigned rangebeg, unsigned rangeend, const std::vector<unsigned int>& v)
{
    std::vector<unsigned int> nv;
    nv.reserve(rangeend - rangebeg - v.size());
    std::vector<unsigned int>::const_iterator next = v.begin();
    // skip out-of-range values in v
    while (next != v.end() && *next < rangebeg) {
        ++next;
    }
    for (unsigned i = rangebeg; i < rangeend; ++i)
    {
         if (next != v.end() && *next == i) {
             ++next;
             continue;
         }
         nv.push_back(i);
    }
    return nv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the array `v[a,b,c......]` is already sorted.
Then, initialse `vn=[]` and traverse through the elements and insert nos from `v[i-1] to v[i] into vn[]`.

Code:

```
void insert_nos(int A, int B)
{
    for(int i=A+1;i<B;i++)
         vn.push_back(i);
}

insert_nos(range_start-1, v[0]);

for(int i=0;i<v.size()-1;i++)
    insert_nos(v[i],v[i+1]);

insert_nos(v[v.size()-1],range_end+1);
```

**Make sure to handle the boundary cases.**

Complexity: **O(n)**

Comment: What is `insert_nos()`?

Comment: sorry, but it got deleted. Added it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version without raw loops:

```
std::array<int, 2> range{0,10};
std::vector<int> items{0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 9};

std::vector<int> v(range.back() - range.front() - items.size());

std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), 
              [iter = items.cbegin(), endIter = items.cend(), i = range.front()] () mutable 
              { while(iter < endIter && i == *iter) { ++iter; ++i; } return i++; });
```

Comment: any nfo on the time complexity of this?